# Scope to get users older then 18 years old by birthday field (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I need to write scope that will help me get users where age will be > 18 years, but I don't have age field in database.
My solutions doesn't works =(

```
 1. scope :adult, -> { where('Time.now.utc.to_date.year - birthday.to_date.year >= 18') }

 2. scope :adults, -> { where('birthday >= ?', age) }

    def age
      Date.today - 18.years
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
scope :adults, -> { where('birthday <= ?', 18.years.from_now) }
```